# How can I stream a log file to a web page using ASP WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, webforms

I want to use an ASP webpage to monitor a realtime log file - I have found solutions using other technologies e.g [frontail](https://github.com/mthenw/frontail), but not using ASP.

I think I need to signalr for realtime communication, and I have spent a few hours now searching for ideas and solutions without any luck. All my searches return info about the ASP and signalr logs themselves.

How can I monitor and stream a log file or multiple log files to a webpage using ASP webforms?

Comment: What is wrong with signalR?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, I'm just not sure how I can use it to monitor a realtime log and am looking for suggestions on how to do it...

Comment: What have you tried? Please, share some code, and I will help adding SignalR

Comment: I had some code that wasn't working but i got it working when i realised that Chrome was having issues with websockets and windows auth. I tried using hangfire to handle a background task with an infinite loop reading my file and sending the new lines via signalr. But hangfire tasks are persistent and I can't find a way to cancel them when someone closes the page. 

Any idea's of another way i can run an infinite loop per page load to check for logfile changes?

Comment: you do speak only about technologies without sharing any code. I can't help you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

you might consider the UpdatePanel / Timer polling approach.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate> 

    Your repeater, datalist, listview, or other databound control here.

    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel> 

<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

Timer1_Tick is the server side method that should rebind the databound control.